# Как сохранить значение массива в рекурсии?

Tags: javascript

Решаю задачу на codewars и не могу понять в чем проблема.

**Задача следующая:** написать функцию, которая будет принимать число и каждую его единицу будет перемножать и записывать промежуточный результат в массив.

Пример:

```
per(1) //вернет []
per(10) //1*0 вернет 0
per(69) //6*9 = 54, 5*4 = 20, 2*0 = 0 .Вернет [54, 20, 0])
per(277777788888899) // Вернет [4996238671872, 438939648, 4478976, 338688, 27648, 2688, 768, 336, 54, 20, 0])
```

Сделал так

```js
var out = [];

function per(n) {
  let arr = n.toString().split("");
  let res = arr[0];
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return [];
  }
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res *= arr[i];
  }

  out.push(res);
  per(res);
  return out;
}

console.log(per(69));
```

Если проверять через консоль, то все работает и результаты правильные. Если проверять на codewars, то он ругается на код при проверке со следующими входными данными:

```
per(69) // почему-то возвращает [0, 54, 20, 0] вместо [54, 20, 0]

per(277777788888899)
//возвращает
 
[0, 54, 20, 0, 4996238671872, 438939648, 4478976, 338688, 27648, 2688, 768, 336, 54, 20, 0]
```

вместо

```
[4996238671872, 438939648, 4478976, 338688, 27648, 2688, 768, 336, 54, 20, 0],
```

У меня есть подозрение, что я ломаю проверку на codewars своей глобальной переменной, куда записываю промежуточный результат. Но знаний не хватает. Не понимаю как внутри рекурсии сохранить значения в массиве out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно передавать массив вторым аргументом. При первом вызове он не будет определен - ничего страшного, можно сделать значение по умолчанию - `[]`

```js
console.log( per(1) );
console.log( per(10) );
console.log( per(69) );
console.log( per(277777788888899) );

function per(n, arr = []) {
  // Только у первого вызова не будет arr: Станет []
  if (n < 10) return arr;

  let mul = ("" + n).split("").reduce((res, digit) => res * digit);
  // Результат умножения цифр

  arr.push(mul);

  return per(mul, arr); // Все последующие вызовы уже со вторым аргументом - массивом.
}
```

И без рекурсии:

```js
console.log( per(1) );
console.log( per(10) );
console.log( per(69) );
console.log( per(277777788888899) );

function per(n) {
  let arr = [];
  
  while (n > 9) {
    n = ("" + n).split("").reduce((res, digit) => res * digit);
    arr.push( n );
  }
  
  return arr;
}
```

Но на codewars любят заниматься <s>хе</s> спортивным сокращением кода...

```js
let per = (n, a = []) => {
  while (n > 9) a.push(  n = ("" + n).split("").reduce((r, d) => r * d)  )
  return a
}

console.log( per(1) );
console.log( per(10) );
console.log( per(69) );
console.log( per(277777788888899) );
```

Кажется короче некуда)

Если не рассматривать `while (n > 9) a.push(  n = eval(("" + n).split("").join("*"))  )`

Answer (score 0):

Можно обернуть весь код еще в одну функцию, тогда массив будет уже не глобальным. Можно передавать массив вторым параметром, вообще избавившись от глобальной переменной